# calculate output current caused by two sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

This is a common source degeneration with `i1` and `i2` are two current sources to model noise generated by the transistor and the resistor. In [this video](https://youtu.be/DhZR70qpp08?t=1807) at 30:07 the professor calculated the current `iout` by some transfer functions from `i1, i2` to `iout`. 
Can anyone explain the method here? 
I understand the transfer function from `i2 to iout` but I don't get what he did to get transfer function from `i1 to iout`.

How can he calculate it that fast?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage at the source terminal is:
$$V_S = -I_1 \times R||g_m = \frac{R}{1 +g_mR}\:I_1$$

And the drain current is:

$$I_D = V_{GS} \times g_m = \frac{g_mR}{1 +g_mR} \: I_1 $$

And finally, we have the output current:

$$I_{OUT} = I_1 - I_D = I_1 -\frac{g_mR I_1}{1 +g_mR} = \frac{I_1 (1 +g_m R)}{1 +g_m R} -\frac{g_mR I_1}{1 +g_mR} = \frac{1}{1 + g_mR}\:I_1 $$

Or try this equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMtmva.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>